# Implement websocket notification in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I would like to notify a user when a specific record changes via someother process (outside of react-admin) in the backend.

For example, status of an order changes and I would like to notify user interested in that order right away in react-admin.

Does anyone have any experience doing this in react-admin? Is there a built-in way do this? If not, are there any resources I can review to implement it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar scheme. Using a custom saga that intercepts 
various Redux actions and sends them through WebSocket:

```
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#custom-sagas
https://medium.com/@pierremaoui/using-websockets-with-redux-sagas-a2bf26467cab
https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html
https://socket.io/docs/client-api/
```